# How to assign different values to keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

In this piece of code I am trying to assign different random values to each of the dictionary keys of a given dictionary. Here is the piece of code I have written till now:

```
import random

player={'a':'','b':'','c':''}
arms=int(input("Enter number of arms : "))
unknown_arm=random.randint(1,arms)

player['a']=unknown_arm
player['b']=unknown_arm

print(player)
```

The problem I am facing is that both the key pairs are assigned to a same value of the random integer generated. How to assign different random values to both of them.

Comment: Hint: Use `for` or `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you store the value of the random integer in a variable. So every time you use the variable you use the same value of it. If you want a new random variable for the second key you need to compute a random number again. So the code would be:

```
    import random
    
    player = {}
    arms = int(input("Enter number of arms: "))
    player['a'] = random.randint(1, arms)
    player['b'] = random.randint(1, arms) #will create a new random number
```

Also you should surround the

```
    arms = int(input("Enter number of arms: "))
```

with a `try` - `except` so that if the user types in "e" it won't cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension, which is a phytonic way of doing it.

```
import random
player_with_values = {k: random.randint(1, arms) for k in player.keys()}
```

If you put it all together:

```
import random
n_players = int(input("Enter number of players : "))
n_arms = int(input("Enter number of arms : "))

players = {str(k): random.randint(1, n_arms) for k in range(n_players)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the range for generating random integers is `1<=N<=arms`:

You can use the following code:

```py
import random

player={'a':'','b':'','c':''}
arms=int(input("Enter number of arms : "))

player = {k: random.randint(1, arms) for k in player}

print(player)
```